# Does an effective cycle supported on a subvariety come from an effective cycle on that subvariety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety and $\gamma\in CH_i(X)$ be an effective cycle. Suppose that $\gamma$ is supported on $Y$ in the sense that $\gamma\in \ker(CH_i(X)\to CH_i(X\setminus Y))$. Then by the localization exact sequence $\gamma$ is in the image of $CH_i(Y)\to CH_i(X)$. There is a priori no reason for $\gamma$ to be the image of an effective cycle. What is an example where $\gamma$ does not come from an effective cycle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $C$ and $D$ be (integral) curves in $\mathbb{P}^2$ of degrees $2$ and $3$ respectively. Consider the inclusion

$$i\colon C \cup D\hookrightarrow\mathbb{P}^2.$$

The image in $CH_1(\mathbb{P}^2)$ of the set of effective cycles in $CH_1(C\cup D)$ is

$$\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0} \ 2H + \mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}\  3H$$

and hence does not contain the class $H$ of a line.  However, $H = i_*([D]-[C])$ is supported on $C\cup D$ and effective.

Comment: I was hoping for examples for all $i$ and mostly had $i=0$ in mind. This example obviously works for all $i$ except for $i=0$. Do you have an idea for $i=0$?

Comment: On an elliptic curve $E$ you can find distinct points $P,Q,R,S$ such that $P + Q = R + S$. Then $P$ is supported on $\{Q,R,S\}$, but is not equal to an effective cycle on this set (as for example $P-Q = 0$ implies that $E\cong \mathbb{P}^1$).